# jQuery - Losing reference to form that is refreshed by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a form that saves a customer address. I have created the following code to read through my list of form text elements and make sure they have all been filled out before I submit the form. However, when the form is submitted and the form is reloaded via Ajax, the jQuery loses reference and will no longer traverse over the form's text elements.

```
$('#cart-addresses :text').each(function (){

        if(sAB == true){
            if(this.id.includes("_0_") && this.id != "cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_address_line_two" && this.value == ""){
                ready = false;
            }
        }else{
            if(this.id != "cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_address_line_two" && this.id != "cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_address_line_two" && this.value == ""){
                ready = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

For other elements that I have loading in via Ajax calls I use something like this which works.

```
$("#cart-addresses input[type=text]").on('keyup',function(e){ myHandler(e);  });
```

However, I do not know how to do the same type of thing to the form so that the Ajax call doesn't cause the reference to be lost.

The Ajax call receives a response with the following javascript.

```
$("#address-content").html("");
$("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "addresses", :locals => { cart: @cart, countries: @countries}) %>").appendTo("#address-content");

$("#shipping-methods").html("");
$("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "shipping_methods", :locals => { cart: @cart}) %>").appendTo("#shipping-methods");


$("#order-details").html("");
$("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "order_details", :locals => { cart_items: @cart_items, totals: @totals}) %>").appendTo("#order-details");

setStates(0);
setStates(1);

isShippingEqaulToBilling();
```

Comment: show ajax's `success` block

Comment: *"when the form is submitted and the form is reloaded via Ajax, "* - Why do you replace the entire form? Can't you read back the information and put it in the existing form?

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm using Ruby on Rails and if you render the form in that manor Rails will auto generate the fields with errors.

Comment: @Amogh I've updated my question

Comment: you cannot do this: `$("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "addresses", :locals => { cart: @cart, countries: @countries}) %>")`, the erb is evaluated before it is sent to the client so that tag does not exist when the jquery is executed.

Comment: @Dallen All of that code is inside a .js.erb file which just generates the js to return. I'm not executing ruby inside of a jquery function in the browser...

Comment: @CannonMoyer then you need single quotes or escaped quotes or the ruby will error

Comment: @Dallen the Ruby implementation works just fine. My question is related to JavaScript and a form that is loaded in vai an Ajax call. If I loaded the response in with Prolog it wouldn't matter. I am having JavaScript issues.

Answer (score 0):

Reference problems can be solved storing the `this` variable:

```
var $context = this;
```

You can use anywhere after storing it.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: i need an snippet of your ajax call usage to make an more direct example (you can change the data, i only need the context loosing)